# where are tokens created by kubectl create token stored (from v1.24 on)?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, token

This question concerns kubernetes v1.24 and up

So I can create tokens for service accounts with

```
kubectl create token myserviceaccount
```

The created token works and serves the purpose, but what I find confusing is that when I `kubectl get sa` SECRETS field of myserviceaccount is still 0. The token doesn't appear in `kubectl get secrets` either.

I've also seen that I can pass `--bound-object-kind` and `--bound-object-name` to `kubectl create token` but this doesn't seem to do anything (visible) either...

Is there a way to see created token? And what is the purpose of --bound.. flags?

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the [docs link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) I've stumbled upon today (I don't know how I've missed it when asking the question because I've spent quite some time browsing through the docs...) I found the information I was looking for. I feel like providing this answer because I find v1d3rm3's answer incomplete and not fully accurate.

The kubernetes docs confirm v1d3rm3's claim (which is btw the key to answering my question):

> The created token is a signed JSON Web Token (JWT).

Since the token is JWT token the server can verify if it has signed it, hence no need to store it. JWTs expiry time is set not because the token is not associated with an object (it actually is, as we'll see below) but because the server has no way of invalidating a token (it would actually need to keep track of invalidated tokens because tokens aren't stored anywhere and any token with good signature is valid). To reduce the damage if a token gets stolen there is an expiry time.

Signed JWT token contains all the necessary information inside of it.

The decoded token (created with `kubectl create token test-sa` where test-sa is service account name) looks like this:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
  ],
  "exp": 1666712616,
  "iat": 1666709016,
  "iss": "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",
  "kubernetes.io": {
    "namespace": "default",
    "serviceaccount": {
      "name": "test-sa",
      "uid": "dccf5808-b29b-49da-84bd-9b57f4efdc0b"
    }
  },
  "nbf": 1666709016,
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa"
}
```

Contrary to v1d3rm3 answer, **This token IS associated with a service account automatically**, as the kubernets docs link confirm and as we can also see from the token content above.

Suppose I have a secret I want to bind my token to (for example `kubectl create token test-sa --bound-kind Secret --bound-name my-secret` where test-sa is service account name and my-secret is the secret I'm binding token to), the decoded token will look like this:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
  ],
  "exp": 1666712848,
  "iat": 1666709248,
  "iss": "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",
  "kubernetes.io": {
    "namespace": "default",
    "secret": {
      "name": "my-secret",
      "uid": "2a44872f-1c1c-4f18-8214-884db5f351f2"
    },
    "serviceaccount": {
      "name": "test-sa",
      "uid": "dccf5808-b29b-49da-84bd-9b57f4efdc0b"
    }
  },
  "nbf": 1666709248,
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa"
}
```

Notice that binding happens inside the token, under **kubernetes.io** key and if you describe my-secret you will still not see the token. So the --bound-... flags weren't visibly (from secret object) doing anything because binding happens inside the token itself...

Instead of decoding JWT tokens, we can also see details in TokenRequest object with

```
kubectl create token test-sa -o yaml
```

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine, but, youdidn't understand my answer. I didn't said that expiration time was set because the missing association. I said is obligatory because of "security reasons"

Comment: @v1d3rm3 sorry then, I deducted it from "...for security reasons, expiration time of a created token not associated with an object..." And thanks a lot for your time and help, I appreciate it!

Comment: When we talk about association, there is a property of direction of association ("token has a secret reference" or "secret has token reference"), it's the source of our miscommunication.

Comment: Expiration time is optional in JWT if it was created from a secret object of type `kubernetes.io/service-account-token`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question it seems that the command “kubectl create token myserviceaccount” is not as you expect because according to the official documentation, when you are configuring another SA, the  token is automatically created and it is referenced by the service account.

Consider that Any tokens for non-existent service accounts will be cleaned up by the token controller.

Regarding to the configuration of the SA check the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-multiple-service-accounts)

If you want to know more about how the authentication works in the service account token works you can consult context you can consult the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/)

Incase that you have Sa set it yo can check how to manage it in the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/)

For establishing bidirectional trust between a node joining the cluster and a control-plane node, consult the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/)

If you desire to check the token assigned, you can follow:

Get information about your Kubernetes secret object. Secrets are used to store access credentials:

```
kubectl get secret --namespace={namespace}
```

output:

```
    NAME                   TYPE                                  DATA          AGE                          
    admin.registrykey      kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1             1h                                       
    default-token-2mfqv    kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3             1h
```

Get details of the service account token.

```
kubectl get secret default-token-2mfqv --namespace={namespace} -o yaml
```

Following is a sample output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
 ca.crt: S0tLS1CR...=
 namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
 token: ZXlKaGJHY...=
kind: Secret
metadata:
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
   kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: df441c69-f4ba-11e6-8157-525400225b53
 creationTimestamp: 2017-02-17T02:43:33Z
 name: default-token-2mfqv
 namespace: default
 resourceVersion: "37"
 selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/default-token-2mfqv
 uid: df5f1109-f4ba-11e6-8157-525400225b53
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Note: The token in the sample output is encoded in base64. You must decode the token and then set this token by using kubectl.

Decode and set the base64-encoded token.

```
kubectl config set-credentials sa-user --token=$(kubectl get secret <secret_name> -o jsonpath={.data.token} | base64 -d)

kubectl config set-context sa-context --user=sa-user
```

In the command, <secret_name> type the name of your service account secret.
Connect to the API server.
curl -k -H "Authorization:Bearer {token}"

You can now use kubectl to access your cluster without a time limit for token expiry.

And finally, [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-) you can read about the –bound flag.

****Considering at 1.24 version this have change ****

Once the Pod is running using a SA you could check:

Generate ServiceAccount token manually

Simply generate tokens manually to use in pipelines or whenever we need to contact the K8s Apiserver:

```
kubectl create token cicd
kubectl create token cicd --duration=999999h
```

Tip: You can inspect the tokens using for example https://jwt.io, just don’t do this with production tokens!

Create a Secret for the ServiceAccount
We can create Secrets manually and assign these to a ServiceAccount:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: cicd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "cicd"
```

if you describe the Secret, we’ll also see that a token was generated for it:

```
kubectl describe secret cicd
```

One big difference is though, that the ServiceAccount doesn’t have a Secret section any longer like before:

```
kubectl get sa cicd -oyaml
```

To find a Secret belonging to a ServiceAccount we need to search for all Secrets having the proper annotation.

Delete a ServiceAccount
If we delete the ServiceAccount then the Secret will also be deleted automatically, just like in previous versions:

```
kubectl delete sa cicd
kubectl get sa,secret # all gone
```

You could check the following video for [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9_yi2YMeNs&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Hi @golder3 the suggestion shared by me, it works to you ?

Comment: the token is not automatically created from kubernetes version 1.24, hence my question...

Comment: Sorry for that I was missing that info i edit my answered considering the version, wishing could help you

Answer (score 0):

Look at `golder3` answer.

---

> Is there a way to see created token?

<s>No, there isn't. Tokens created with `Token Request API` are one time creation. Kubernetes doesn't manage tokens, the only way to manage tokens is associate it with a Secret or Pod object. Tokens are JWT objects, so, for security reasons, expiration time of a created token not associated with an object is, by default, of one hour. It can be configured with `--duration` property.</s>

> And what is the purpose of --bound.. flags?

<s>The purpose of `--bound` flags is to associate a token with a specific object.</s>

---

From v1.24, you've to manually create tokens.

### Using TokenRequest API

It depends of the use case, but it's not so easy to manage these tokens. They're created with the command `kubectl create`, some examples are:

```bash
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

if the `Service Account` is in a specific `namespace`, then you need to define on command:

```bash
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME -n NAMESPACE
```

You can defined expiration time too:

```bash
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME --duration 5h
```

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-

### Token associated with a Secret

To create a `token` associated with a `secret` object, you can use `kubectl apply` with a file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: demo-token # the name of secret 
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "name_of_sa" # the name of the ServiceAccount
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Then, just execute:

```
kubectl apply -f file.yml
```

Or, if the ServiceAccount is in a specific namespace

```
kubectl apply -f file.yml -n NAMESPACE
```

Comment: the question was where the token created with kubectl create token is stored, not how to create it (btw I wrote in the question how it can be created...) or how to associate a token to a secret...